# How to render useEffect only once if 2 states are changing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a recipe Website in which I have two changing states **Category** and **Page**.
I want to dipatch some action based on changing category and page.

So , I used one useEffect for category and one useEffect for page.

```
const [category, setCategory] = useState('All');
const page = query.get('page') || 1;
useEffect(()=>{
   dispatch(getCards(category,1))
   navigate(`/card?category=${category}&page=1`);
},[dispatch,category])

useEffect(()=>{
   dispatch(getCards(category,page))
   navigate(`/card?category=${category}&page=${page}`);
},[dispatch,page])
```

Now, I want that, if both the states changed at once , then only one useEffect should be fired .
Is there any way.

Like, when category changes, then useEffect for category is called, it dispatches the corresponding action and navigates, then again after navigation, same dispatch action is called , so, I don't want this same action to be called twice.

Also, in the initial render, this same action is called twice(because category useEffect and page useEffect ran once in initial render)

Answer (score 1):

- Create new state to manage page changes
- Update the page number to 1 in the function where you update the category.
- Update your useEffect as follows to trigger only on page changes

```
const [page, setPage] useState(query.get('page') || 1);
const updateCategory = (_category) => {
  setCategory(_category);
  setPage(1);
}

useEffect(()=>{
   dispatch(getCards(category,page))
   navigate(`/card?category=${category}&page=${page}`);
//eslint-disable-next-line
},[dispatch,page])
```

Comment: This works , but I want when category changes , the navigate link should become navigate(`/card?category=${category}&page=1`) i.e page should become 1 (as mentioned in code above).
Like, how I will get to know in useEffect that what(category or page) changed.